# Two columns condition in different rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with about a 100 columns and 30000 of rows.
Look something like this:

```
site_id   cell_id   sector_id    value1     value2
  1          1           1          70        23
  1          2           1          40        20
  1          3           1          67        35
  1          5           2          42        60
  1          6           2          65        30
  1          7           2          62        62
  2          11          1          67        11
  2          12          1          45        22
  2          13          1          65        15
```

For the same sector_id of one site_id, if value1>=65 than any cell_id in that same sector with value2<25 would be classified as "LOW_LOAD_CELL". 
Desired output would be:

```
site_id   cell_id   sector_id    value1     value2   cell_status
  1          1           1          70        23     LOW_LOAD_CELL
  1          2           1          40        20     LOW_LOAD_CELL
  1          3           1          67        35
  1          5           2          42        60
  1          6           2          65        30
  1          7           2          62        62
  2          11          1          67        11     LOW_LOAD_CELL
  2          12          1          45        22     LOW_LOAD_CELL
  2          13          1          65        15     LOW_LOAD_CELL
 ...
```

I don't know how to approach in SQL, honestly. I have tried with WHEN CASE, but I stacked when I needed to write condition for value2.

Comment: Your sample data does not conform to your rules.

Comment: If it was a last row with sector_id = 2, you was right, I've edited. Thank you.

Comment: This won't help and I'm sorry about it, but I think your problem is your trying to get unrelationnal data from a relationnal database with a language that fit relationnal databases (SQL)... I would be very surprised if a model that includes relations with 100 columns met the third normal form...

Comment: I think it's possible but with a few queries, it's hard to with one.

Answer (score 8):

try:

```
select *
, case when value1>=65 and min(value2) over (partition by site_id, sector_id)<25 then 'LOW_LOAD_CELL' end cell_status 
from your_table
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the logic you actually want is:

```
select t.*,
       (case when max(value1) over (partition by site_it, sector_id) >= 65 and
                  value2 < 25
             then 'LOW_LOAD_CELL'
        end) as cell_status 
from t ;
```

This conforms to your data -- if any row for a sector/site combination has `value1` of 65 or over, then that cell is a low load cell when its `value2` is less than 25.

Comment: If in same one site_id and same one sector_id any cell_id have value_1 >= 65 than any cell_id which have value_2<25 in the same site_id and same sector_id is classified as "LOW_LOAD_CELL"

Comment: @jovicbg . . . Cells 2 and 12 suggest that the rule is the other way around.

Comment: No, if in that same sector of the same site_id any cell has value1 over 65, then any cell in that site_id and sector_id which have value2 under 25 is LOW_LOAD_CELL.  Cells 1 and 11 has value1 over 65, and cells 2 and 12 value2 under 25, so they are LOW_LOAD_CELL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select t.*, case when t2.cnt > 0 and value2 < 25 then 'LOW_LOAD_CELL' end cell_status
from mytable as t left join
( select site_id, sector_id, count(*) cnt from mytable where 
  value1 >= 65 group by site_id, sector_id ) as  t2
on t.site_id = t2.site_id and t.sector_id = t2.sector_id
```